# Windows Server 2012 foundation not asking for user login

Tags: windows

I am having a problem with a Windows Server 2012 Foundation Computer. It's a new server which I have just set up. For some reason, which is not clear to me, the server is not requiring computers on the same LAN as the server to log in to access server drives.

Based on past experience, Windows Server (in fact all windows machines) require users to have an account and log in before accessing network (shared) resources. Not this one. I set up a couple of network shares and anyone connected to the network can use them. Remote Desktop users still have to log in, but not locally connected users.

It's a new server. I have simply set it up as a Domain Controller - that's it. I had a look at Group Policy Editor, but couldn't figure out how to do anything there to fix the problem. Any input welcome. I am baffled by this one.

Comment: `couldn't figure out how to do anything there to fix the problem` Just to be clear, is your problem is about the fact that you don't need any username/password to access some shared folders ?

Comment: Are the users not logging in to the domain?  If not, are they logging on to local accounts on the workstations, or to another domain?  File access is controlled by share permissions and file permissions--what are the file and share permissions set to?  We need far more information about your environment to help...

Comment: `Windows Server 2012 foundation not asking for user login` You are already authenticated or ressource is configured to allow "everyone"...

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for looking at this. Apologies for the delay in responding. I have been moving house. In my experience, when you try to access a server on a network, the first thing the server asks you to do is to log in using a username and password. This one doesn't. The users are logging on to local accounts on the workstations. They are not joined to the domain. The file share permissions are not configured to allow "everyone". They are configured to allow specific domain users or groups of users (e.g. Domain Admins, or Domain Users) access to those resources.

Comment: So, yes, the problem is that the server appears to be allowing anyone who is connected to the local LAN (subnet) access to all shared resources on the server. In my experience of setting up Windows Servers previously (I have set up a number), the server does not allow you do access it until you log into it and/or join the domain. So, this is unusual. The previous installs were Windows Server 2003, then 2012 Essentials and then a slightly more complicated setup 2012 Standard and Essentials running as Domain Controller in a Virtual Machine. This is Foundation, so maybe it works differently ?

Answer (score -1):

Windows 2012 Foundation does not require password when the party accessing the network shared resources is in the same domain as the server.